# SocketException Permission denied - CakePHP 2.3

Tags: php, cakephp, centos

I receive that error when try send e-mail with **CakePHP 2.3.0**.
My Cloud configuration is:

- PHP 5.4
- Apache 2.2
- MySQL 5.5
- CakePHP 2.3.0

Sorry about my english.

---

```
2013-03-06 09:15:05 Error: [SocketException] Permission denied
Request URL: /notifications/sendContact
Stack Trace:
#0 /var/www/html/site/lib/Cake/Network/Email/SmtpTransport.php(96): CakeSocket->connect()
#1 /var/www/html/site/lib/Cake/Network/Email/SmtpTransport.php(60): SmtpTransport->_connect()
#2 /var/www/html/site/lib/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php(1065): SmtpTransport->send(Object(CakeEmail))
#3 /var/www/html/site/app/Controller/NotificationsController.php(41): CakeEmail->send()
#4 [internal function]: NotificationsController->sendContact()
#5 /var/www/html/site/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(485): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(NotificationsController), Array)
#6 /var/www/html/site/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(186): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
#7 /var/www/html/site/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(161): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(NotificationsController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#8 /var/www/html/site/app/webroot/index.php(102): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#9 {main}
2013-03-06 09:15:05 Error: Fatal Error (256): [CakeException] Unknown status code
#0 /var/www/html/site/lib/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php(212): CakeResponse->statusCode(13)
#1 [internal function]: ExceptionRenderer->error400(Object(SocketException))
#2 /var/www/html/site/lib/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php(175): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/html/site/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(122): ExceptionRenderer->render()
#4 [internal function]: ErrorHandler::handleException(Object(SocketException))
#5 {main} in [/var/www/html/site/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php, line 131]
2013-03-06 09:15:05 Error: [InternalErrorException] Internal Server Error
Request URL: /notifications/sendContact
Stack Trace:
#0 /var/www/html/site/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(183): ErrorHandler::handleFatalError(256, '[CakeException]...', '/var/www/html/p...', 131)
#1 [internal function]: ErrorHandler::handleError(256, '[CakeException]...', '/var/www/html/p...', 131, Array)
#2 /var/www/html/site/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(131): trigger_error('[CakeException]...', 256)
#3 [internal function]: ErrorHandler::handleException(Object(SocketException))
#4 {main}
2013-03-06 09:15:05 Error: Fatal Error (256): [CakeException] Unknown status code
#0 /var/www/html/site/lib/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php(212): CakeResponse->statusCode(13)
#1 [internal function]: ExceptionRenderer->error400(Object(SocketException))
#2 /var/www/html/site/lib/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php(175): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/html/site/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(122): ExceptionRenderer->render()
#4 [internal function]: ErrorHandler::handleException(Object(SocketException))
#5 {main} in [/var/www/html/site/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php, line 131]
2013-03-06 09:15:05 Error: [InternalErrorException] Internal Server Error
Request URL: /notifications/sendContact
Stack Trace:
#0 /var/www/html/site/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(183): ErrorHandler::handleFatalError(256, '[CakeException]...', '/var/www/html/p...', 131)
#1 [internal function]: ErrorHandler::handleError(256, '[CakeException]...', '/var/www/html/p...', 131, Array)
#2 /var/www/html/site/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(926): call_user_func('ErrorHandler::h...', 256, '[CakeException]...', '/var/www/html/p...', 131, Array)
#3 /var/www/html/site/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(899): App::_checkFatalError()
#4 [internal function]: App::shutdown()
#5 {main}
```

---

## email.php

```
public $gmail = array(
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'from' => array('patric.....@gmail.com' => 'Patrick Maciel'),
    'port'=>'465',
    'timeout'=>'30',
    'auth' => true,
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'username'=>'patrick......@gmail.com',
    'password'=>'.......',
    'client' => null,
    'log' => false
);
```

---

## php info (centOs)

```
-bash-4.1# yum info php
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.globo.com
 * epel: mirror.globo.com
 * extras: mirror.globo.com
 * updates: mirror.globo.com
Installed Packages
Name       : php
Arch       : i686
Version    : 5.4.12
Release    : 1.el6.remi
Size       : 8.2 M
Repo       : installed
From repo  : remi
Summary    : PHP scripting language for creating dynamic web sites
URL        : http://www.php.net/
License    : PHP and Zend and BSD
Description: PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language. PHP attempts to make it
           : easy for developers to write dynamically generated web pages. PHP also
           : offers built-in database integration for several commercial and
           : non-commercial database management systems, so writing a
           : database-enabled webpage with PHP is fairly simple. The most common
           : use of PHP coding is probably as a replacement for CGI scripts.
           :
           : The php package contains the module which adds support for the PHP
           : language to Apache HTTP Server.

Available Packages
Name       : php
Arch       : i386
Version    : 5.3.22
Release    : 1.w5
Size       : 1.3 M
Repo       : webtatic
Summary    : PHP scripting language for creating dynamic web sites
URL        : http://www.php.net/
License    : PHP
Description: PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language. PHP attempts to make it
           : easy for developers to write dynamically generated web pages. PHP also
           : offers built-in database integration for several commercial and
           : non-commercial database management systems, so writing a
           : database-enabled webpage with PHP is fairly simple. The most common
           : use of PHP coding is probably as a replacement for CGI scripts.
           :
           : The php package contains the module which adds support for the PHP
           : language to Apache HTTP Server.

-bash-4.1# php -m
[PHP Modules]
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
imap
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
memcache
mhash
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
pspell
readline
recode
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
snmp
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tidy
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]

-bash-4.1#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently your PHP is not allowed to connect to the specified SMTP server. Did you properly configure your email-settings? (SMTP server, port, username, password etc).

A template for these settings is included with CakePHP in the file: app/Config/email.php.default (https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.2.7/app/Config/email.php.default)

You need to copy this file to `app/Config/email.php` and modify the settings for your environment.

After that, you'll have to specify the right configuration when sending emails

A more thorough explanation can be found in the manual:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#configuration

#### update

Another option is that SELinux security-bits dissallow PHP/Apache to make network connections.

There are several security-bits, but this seems a likely candidate: `httpd_can_network_connect` .

You can temporarily allow PHP/Apache to make network connections using this:
`setsebool httpd_can_network_connect`

And make the setting 'permanent' using the `-P` parameter;
`setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect`

For an overview of all SELibux booleans;

http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/SelinuxBooleans

Comment: Another option is that SELinux security-bits dissallow PHP/Apache to make network connections. There are several security-bits, but this seems a likely candidate: `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on` http://yml.com/fv-b-1-619/selinux--apache-httpd--php-establishing-socket-connections-using-fsockopen---et-al.html for an overview of all settings; http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/SelinuxBooleans

Comment: When I use -P doens't work (I don't know why). Just `setsebool httpd_can_network_connect on` works very well, and cakephp send email. Now, I need know, how can I make this command permanent.

Comment: Maybe you need 'sudo' permissions in order to make permanent changes; Although you may not have these permissions; type `sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on` and enter your *own* password when asked. If you don't have sudo permissions, but have 'root' access, you my try to run setsebool -P as root.

Comment: I don't because I logged in my cloud with root (not have other user, just root).

Comment: Being 'root' should give you all permissions. However, the `'-P'` option will save the settings to a policy-file (http://linux.die.net/man/8/setsebool). It may be possible that your 'cloud' is configured in a way that parts of your installation are 'shared' by other users as well. Its best to ask this particular question to the support of your hosting-provider. Anyway, as long as your server is not rebooted, the setting should stay fixed, but you need to remember to set it again if the server is rebooted :)

Answer (score 1):

**getsebool -a**

Check **httpd_can_network_connect**

if off, set it to on

**setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on**

It works for me !!